# Localhost exception when selenium automation test fails due to timing out in finding an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, exception

How do I change this exception within my automated tests:

*The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:2064/session/dfc2b7dfad0d464f95f5bbd4d8081580/element/0.10309002696750724-127/element timed out after 60 seconds.*

Whenever my tests fail, I get the exception above. The reason why it does fail, however, is because it cannot find a specific element. Whenever it cannot find an element it throws the exception. How do I get around this to throw an exception that the user would understand?  What is the best way to deal with situations where an exception is thrown everytime it cannot find an element on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper around the find_element call to catch the error and return something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use  try - catch block to wait for the element.

```
try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
        .className("sessionHeader")));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {                
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();    
}
```